# From List<Map<String, Object>>of HashMap objects want to remove duplicate values for one of the property in Hashmap in java 8 ,

Tags: java

Attaching code snippet

```
List<Map<String,A>> listm=new ArrayList<>();

Map<String,A> map=new HashMap<>();
A a1=new A();
a1.setAge("30");
a1.setName("Mani");
map.put("1", a1);

A a2 =new A();
a2.setAge("31");
a2.setName("sasi");
Map<String,A> map1=new HashMap<>();
map1.put("2", a2);

A a3=new A();
a3.setAge("31");
a3.setName("Naveen");
Map<String,A> map2=new HashMap<>();

map2.put("3", a3);
listm.add(map);
listm.add(map1);
listm.add(map2);

List<Map<String, A>>    list = listH.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
               .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the above lambda expression is not removing the duplicate Age object, response should be only 2 records. One with are group 30 and 31, as 31 is duplicate

Comment: This code doesn't compile - what is `listH`?

Comment: Why do you have `List` of `Map`s? Each `Map` has only a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameters filtering on:

```
.filter(entry-> Collections.frequency(listH.values(), entry.getValue()) > 1)
```